# Add a THREE.Points to scene: THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, three.js

i'm trying to add a system particles, a THREE.Points to the scene, but i have this error:

"THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D. undefined"

The code:

```
var backCount = 1800;
var particlesG = new THREE.Geometry();

for (var p = 0; p < backCount; p++) {
    var backgroundP = new THREE.Vector3();
    backgroundP.x = Math.random() * 3000 - 1500;
    backgroundP.y = Math.random() * 3000 - 1500;
    backgroundP.z = Math.random() * 3000 - 1500;
    particlesG.vertices.push(backgroundP);
}

var pMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({color: 0xFFFFFF});

var particleSystemS = THREE.Points(particlesG, pMaterial);


scene.add(particleSystemS);
```

Thanks

Comment: don't you need a "new" keyword for points, too?

Answer (score 2):

Add new before `THREE.Points`.

`var particleSystemS = new THREE.Points(particlesG, pMaterial);`